# post to php in android always return null

Tags: php, android

I have problem posting to my php. 
I try to post data to my php but it allways return null.
I don't know it's from my android code or php that I get null pointer.
can any one tell me where is the problem.
thanks.
this is my php code:

```
     <?php

$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$function = $data['function'];

switch ($function) {
    case'get_my_ads':
        $user_id = $data['user_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `register_ads` WHERE `user_id` = '$user_id' ";
        $query = mysqli_query(connect(), $query);
        $result = array();

        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $html ='
            <table style="direction: rtl;text-align: right">
                <tr>
                    <td>نام واحد:</td>
                    <td>'.$row["name_vahed"].'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>زمینه فعالیت:</td>
                    <td>'.$row["zamine"].'</td>
                </tr>

            </table>';
            /*$tmp['name_vahed']= $row["name_vahed"];
            $tmp['zamine']    = $row["zamine"];
            $tmp['shoar']     = $row["shoar"];
            $tmp['ostan']     = $row["ostan"];
            $tmp['shahr']     = $row["shahr"];
            $tmp['adress']    = $row["adress"];
            $tmp['tel']       = $row["tel"];
            $tmp['mobile']    = $row["mobile"];
            $tmp['web']       = $row["web"];*/
            $result[]         =$html;
        }

        break;
    case'register_ads':
        $user_id = $data['user_id'];
        $name_vahed = $data['name_vahed'];
        $zamine = $data['zamine'];
        $shoar = $data['shoar'];
        $address = $data['address'];
        $ostnha = $data['ostnha'];
        $shahr = $data['name_vahed'];
        $tel = $data['tel'];
        $mobile = $data['mobile'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $web = $data['web'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO register_ads (`id` ,`user_id`,`name_vahed` ,`zamine` ,`shoar` ,`ostan` ,`shahr` ,`adress`,`tel`,`mobile`,`email`,`web`)
                        VALUES (
                                  NULL ,'$user_id', '$name_vahed', '$zamine', '$shoar', '$ostnha', '$shahr', '$address','$tel','$mobile','$email','$web'
                        );";
        $query = mysqli_query(connect(), $query);

        $result = array('result'=>'ok');
        break;
    case 'update_user_info':
        $user_id = $data['user_id'];
        $name = $data['name'];
        $username = $data['username'];
        $family = $data['family'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $tel = $data['tel'];

        if($user_id == "")
            $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id` ,`username` ,`password` ,`name` ,`family` ,`email` ,`tel`)
                        VALUES (
                        NULL , '$username', '$password', '$name', '$family', '$email', '$tel'
                        );";
        else
            $query = "update `users` set name = '$name', family='$family', email='$email', `password`='$password', tel='$tel'  where id= $user_id";

        $query = mysqli_query(connect(), $query);

        $result = array('result'=>$query);

        break;
    case'user_info':
        $user_id = $data['user_id'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$user_id' ";
        $query = mysqli_query(connect(), $query);

        $result = array();

        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $tmp['id']       = $row["id"];
            $tmp['username'] = $row["username"];
            $tmp['password'] = $row["password"];
            $tmp['name']   = $row["name"];
            $tmp['family'] = $row["family"];
            $tmp['email']  = $row["email"];
            $tmp['tel']    = $row["tel"];
            $result[]      =$tmp;
        }
        break;
    case'login':
        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND  `password` = '$password' ";
        $query = mysqli_query(connect(), $query);

        $result = array();

        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $tmp['id']       = $row["id"];
            $tmp['username'] = $row["username"];
            $tmp['password'] = $row["password"];
            $tmp['name']   = $row["name"];
            $tmp['family'] = $row["family"];
            $tmp['email']  = $row["email"];
            $tmp['tel']    = $row["tel"];
            $result[]      =$tmp;
        }
        break;
    case'search':
        $search = $data['search'];
        $type    = $data['type'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE type = $type AND  `name` LIKE '%".$search."%'";
        $query = mysqli_query(connect(), $query);

        $result = array();
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $tmp['id'] = $row["id"];
            $tmp['name'] = $row["name"];
            $tmp['parent'] = $row["parent"];
            $tmp['image_id'] = $row["image_id"];
            $tmp['content'] = $row["content"];
            $tmp['type'] = $row["type"];
            $tmp['html'] = $row["html"];
            $result[]=$tmp;
        }
        break;
    case'categories':
        $id      = $data['id'];
        $parent  = $data['parent'];
        $type    = $data['type'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `categories` where parent = $parent AND type = $type";
        $query = mysqli_query(connect(), $query);

        $result = array();
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            $tmp['id'] = $row["id"];
            $tmp['name'] = $row["name"];
            $tmp['parent'] = $row["parent"];
            $tmp['image_id'] = $row["image_id"];
            $tmp['content'] = $row["content"];
            $tmp['type'] = $row["type"];
            $tmp['html'] = $row["html"];
            $result[]=$tmp;
        }
        break;
}
function connect(){
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "a", "and");
    $link->set_charset("utf8");
    return $link;
}
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

and this one is my android:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.hamodeveloper.ir/android.php");
                String responseBody;
                try{
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("function","get_my_ads"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id","104"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                Log.e("Respons", responseBody);
                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
```

Comment: You need to provide the logcat ERROR output here.. That will help to get answer of your question..

Comment: your service itslef is giving error plz chk if ur service is correct use postman client to check the same

Comment: try making the request without android before, so you can see if your php is right. You can easily do this with:
https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: Test your web service first then try to integrate in your android application.  so you will not round up for this problem.

Comment: please complete the code of the php

Comment: Thanks for help. I test php post with hurl.it and again it return null !!!

Comment: What is returning null? Please be much more exact.

Answer (score 0):

Your php script can never work as it expects a json text. But your Android client is not sending that. It sends key value pairs.

Remove the first two lines and change

```
$function = $data['function'];
```

to

```
$function = $_POST['function'];
```